# KendoGrid Export to Excel removes spaces in the exported file

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I'm trying to export Kendogrid data to excel file.
Below is the sample page where I tried to replicate the same.

The exported excel file has all the space removed between the words, which is an issue.

http://dojo.telerik.com/EtUj/6

Please help if anyone has any solution or workaround.

Thanks